# Angular Quickstart fails karma testing out of the box

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

The official Angular quickstart is not able to run karma tests after a clean install on Windows 10. I typed the following 4 commands and nothing else:

```
C:\projects\temp>git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git
C:\projects\temp>cd C:\projects\temp\quickstart  
C:\projects\temp\quickstart>npm install    
...install logs omitted for brevity  
C:\projects\temp\quickstart>npm start  
...app launched successfully, but logs omitted for brevity  
C:\projects\temp\quickstart>npm test  
...Error shown in complete logs below
```

The full error message resulting after the final command is as follows:

```
C:\projects\temp\quickstart>npm test

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 pretest C:\projects\temp\quickstart
> npm run build


> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build C:\projects\temp\quickstart
> tsc -p src/


> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 test C:\projects\temp\quickstart
> concurrently "npm run build:watch" "karma start karma.conf.js"

[0]
[0] > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build:watch C:\projects\temp\quickstart
[0] > tsc -p src/ -w
[0]
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:49.385:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/projects/temp/quickstart/testing/**/*.js" does not match any file.
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:49.406:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/projects/temp/quickstart/testing/**/*.ts" does not match any file.
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:49.407:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/projects/temp/quickstart/testing/**/*.js.map" does not match any file.
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:49.891:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:49.906:WARN [karma]: Port 9876 in use
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:49.908:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9877/
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:49.908:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:49.958:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:51.821:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "C:/projects/temp/quickstart/src/app/app.component.js".
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:51.843:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "C:/projects/temp/quickstart/src/app/app.component.spec.js".
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:51.850:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "C:/projects/temp/quickstart/src/app/app.module.js".
[0] 2:33:51 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:51.873:INFO [watcher]: Changed file "C:/projects/temp/quickstart/src/main.js".
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:51.965:INFO [Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket pXysNFDP8RC3agm8AAAA with id 9156960
[1] 01 06 2017 14:33:52.077:INFO [karma]: Delaying execution, these browsers are not ready: Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0)
```

What needs to change in order for `npm test` to succeed out of the box on Windows 10?

Comment: Not an answer so I'll keep it as a comment, but consider using angular-cli to create your framework. That is a much more flexible option then using the angular quickstart project and I think you should find the generated karma tests work out of the box. https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: @Duncan Your suggestion of the `angular-cli` worked out of the box.  If you would like to write that up as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted and +1.  For the sake of other readers, you might want to copy 8 or 10 lines of commands from the Angular documentation including commands people can type to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular quickstart project has largely been superseded by the Angular CLI. I would suggest using the CLI it for any new projects as it not only gives you an initial framework for your application, but it will also generate the additional boilerplate needed as you extend your application.

Before installing Angular CLi, ensure you have an up to date version of Node (6.9.0 or higher) and NPM (3 or higher). Also there may be other prerequisites not listed in the documentation, to install on an Android system I found it also needed Python 2.7 and g++ installed.

Install with:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

To create a new project:

```
ng new PROJECT-NAME
cd PROJECT-NAME
ng serve
```

`ng new` will take some time to complete as in addition to building the project structure it also does the `npm install`.

Run unit tests with `ng test` and end-to-end tests with `ng e2e`.
Both `ng test` and `ng serve` will run continuously watching for changes and rebuilding the affected code. You can even leave both running in separate windows if you wish.

`ng generate BLUEPRINT` will generate new code, blueprints include module, component, service, class, directive, enum, guard, interface, pipe
Other useful commands:. You may want to experiment with this a bit before you write a real app: by default each component or service goes into its own subdirectory and is added to the top level app module, but you can explicitly create modules to provide additional structure if you wish.

- `ng build`: builds your application into the output path.
- `ng doc KEYWORD`: opens angular documentation for that keyword.
- `ng eject`: ejects the app and outputs webpack configuration
- `ng lint`: lints the project
- `ng xi18n`: extracts i18n messages from the project.

Answer (score 1):

This is not answer, just give more case to find out root cause.
I followed steps which you described and got this:

```
D:\Project\temp\quickstart>npm test

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 pretest D:\Project\temp\quickstart
> npm run build


> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build D:\Project\temp\quickstart
> tsc -p src/


> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 test D:\Project\temp\quickstart
> concurrently "npm run build:watch" "karma start karma.conf.js"

[0]
[0] > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build:watch D:\Project\temp\quickstart
[0] > tsc -p src/ -w
[0]
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:04.733:WARN [watcher]: Pattern 
"D:/Project/temp/quickstart/testing/**/*.js" does not match any file.
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:04.746:WARN [watcher]: Pattern 
"D:/Project/temp/quickstart/testing/**/*.ts" does not match any file.
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:04.747:WARN [watcher]: Pattern 
"D:/Project/temp/quickstart/testing/**/*.js.map" does not match any file.
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:05.103:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open 
http://localhost:9876/
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:05.120:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.0 server started at 
http://0.0.0.0:9876/
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:05.120:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with 
unlimited concurrency
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:05.156:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:06.742:INFO [Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: 
Connected on socket GGConP8Ks64GubSYAAAA with id 70486747
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:07.822:INFO [watcher]: Changed file 
"D:/Project/temp/quickstart/src/app/app.component.js".
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:07.837:INFO [watcher]: Changed file 
"D:/Project/temp/quickstart/src/app/app.component.spec.js".
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:07.856:INFO [watcher]: Changed file 
"D:/Project/temp/quickstart/src/app/app.module.js".
[0] 10:34:07 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:07.865:INFO [watcher]: Changed file 
"D:/Project/temp/quickstart/src/main.js".
[1] 02 06 2017 22:34:08.084:INFO [karma]: Delaying execution, these browsers 
are not ready: Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0)
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.159 secs / 
0.149 secs)
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.117 secs / 
0.112 secs)
```